# SQL Trigger to create foreign key row

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have an `information` table and a `version` table. I have a trigger that inserts a row in `version` before an insert in `information` occurs. My problem is that I need to use `version.id` (of the newly created row) for `information.version_id` (row about to be created).

I know how to create the trigger and insert in the `version` table, but how do I capture the version id to be used in the insert for `information`?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

```
set  @last_id=LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: *also you can do* ...no, you can't.  That breaks down dramatically with concurrency.  `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is always *your* last insert.  The alternative isn't.